# Will old, pre-explored worlds never have strongholds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Supposedly [strongholds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold) only spawn between 640 and 1152 blocks from the origin and there are only three per world.  On the SMP server I play on, all that land has been explored for a very long time, so it obviously won't be regenerated unless somehow deleted.  Does this mean that the strongholds will never spawn?  Can they be generated in new chunks that are further out if they don't exist yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All chunks generated before 1.8 will use the old world generation algorithm. They will never contain strongholds unless they are deleted and regenerated. <del>Also, chunks from 1.8.x have a much lower stronghold-spawning rate, so even if 1.9+ generation will spawn a stronghold there, the 1.8 chunks will be devoid of them.</del> However, newly generated chunks will contain strongholds, so all is not lost.

If you wish to find them, I'd recommend going to a 1.8+ chunk (there will be a visible line where the generation changed) and use an Eye of Ender.

EDIT:
It seems that 1.0.0 has not in fact implemented the increased spawning that was promised. Silly Mojang! However, the rest of the post still holds.

Comment: So even if all the usual possible spawn spots for the stronghold are already generated, it will generate more?  Is the 3-per-world limit and spawn range that the wiki mentions inaccurate/out-of-date?

Comment: @Nick – Hmm, you are correct about the 3-per-world thing. It was supposed to be fixed in 1.9, but it seems that it was not. Hopefully, it will come in an update soon. If you want to find exactly which chunks contain strongholds, you can use this tool:
http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v2015-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-ect-finder/

If the strongholds appear in already-generated chunks, you have 2 options: (1) remove and regen chunks, or (2) if there are few 1.8+ chunks, change the seed until the strongholds move. If the strongholds are outside the chunks, you're good!

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotal answer: We have a stronghold discovered in a world that was started in Alpha. It was in previously unexplored territory. We had to go to a part of the world explored in 1.8 & use the eye of Ender to find it.

(Thankfully the end portal was intact.)

Comment: What coordinates was it at?  Was it within 640-1152 blocks of the origin?

Comment: x = -496, z = 901. Don't have Y offhand, but it's under an ocean biome, so it's going to be deep.

Comment: that's 1028 blocks from the origin; where it could spawn normally.  The multiplayer map I'm on is totally explored around the origin, up to and past the typical 1152 figure given by the wiki.

Comment: Then you're not going to see one. :(